# How to collapse all children blocks at once in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to show and hide multiple block in parent container = how to do it in Bootstrap?

```
<div id="parent1">
<div>Child 1</div>
<div class="child-info collapse">Info 1</div>
<div>Child 2</div>
<div class="child-info collapse">Info 2</div>
<div>Child 3</div>
<div class="child-info collapse">Info 3</div>
</div>
```

How to show/hide all at once in parent container - if it possible without additional JavaScript code. I read documentation but still it is not clear how to do it - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```js
$(function() {

  var active = true;

  $('#collapse-all').click(function() {
    if (active) {
      active = false;
      $('.panel-collapse').fadeToggle('show');
      $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', '');
    } else {
      active = true;
      $('.panel-collapse').fadeToggle('hide');
      $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel.panel-parent {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel.panel-parent h4.panel-title {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="collapse-all">
    <!-- First Panel -->
    <div class="panel panel-parent">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-parent">
                 Parent
             </h4>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse-parent" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <!-- First Panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
                 Child #1
             </h4>

            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
                desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente
                igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones
                de Lorem Ipsum..</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Second Panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
                 Child #2
             </h4>

            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
                desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente
                igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones
                de Lorem Ipsum..</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Third Panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">
                 Child #3
             </h4>

            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
                desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente
                igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones
                de Lorem Ipsum..</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">Where are the kids??</div>
</div>
```